# Kotlin code dollars into dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels & cents?

Tags: function, kotlin, split

(I'm relatively new, having started the "Software Development" degree & just finished my first Qtr of the school year, so, try not to go get too technical on me just yet. lol)

Using Kotlin--

How do I get "3 Dollars, 1 Dime, 1 Nickel, 0 Pennies" from input of "3.15"?

I've gotten it so that I can get the individual amount left, but can't get it to execute in the above format, as a whole block.

I've tried various ways of coding this (shown below).

PS:
I'm open to any & all changes, albeit I *need* need to keep the func part as **double**, &, the "if, if else, else" **plurallization**.(Ie: if it's "1 **dollar**" or "2 **dollars**" needs to stay the same).

Here's the code itself:
fun main(){

```
if  (getDollar(1.22) <= 0.0)
{
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(1.22)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if

  (getDollar(1.22) == 1.0)
{
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(1.22)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
  else {
  (getDollar (1.22) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(1.22)*100/100) + " Dollars");
  };

         /*  break */

if  (getQuarter(1.22) <= 0.0)
{
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(1.22)*100/100) + " Quarter");
}
else if

  (getQuarter(1.22) <= 1)
{
   println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(1.22)*100/100) + " Quarter");
}
  else {
  (getQuarter (1.22) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(1.22)*100/100) + " Quarters");
  };

   /* break  */ 

  if  (getDime(1.22) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(1.22)*100/100) + " Dime");
}
else if (getDime(1.22) <= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(1.22)*100/100) + " Dime");
}
  else {
  (getDime (1.22) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(1.22)*100/100) + " Dimes");
  };
 
 /* break */

   if  (getNickel(1.22) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(1.22)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if (getNickel(1.22) <= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(1.22)*100/100) + " Nickel");
}
  else {
  (getNickel (1.22) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(1.22)*100/100) + " Nickels");
  };

/* break  */

  if (changeDue(1.22) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(1.22)*1000/100) + " Penny");
}
else if (changeDue(1.22) >= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(1.22)*1000/100) + " Penny");
}
  else {
  (changeDue (1.22) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(1.22)*1000/100) + " Pennies");
  };

 println("")
```

/*  Break  */

```
if  (getDollar(.38) <= 0.0)
{
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(.38)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if

(getDollar(.38) == 1.0)
{
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(.38)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
  else {
  (getDollar (.38) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDollar(.38)*100/100) + " Dollars");
  };

         /*  break */

 if  (getQuarter(.38) <= 0.0)
{
    println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(.38)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if

   (getQuarter(.38) <= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(.38)*100/100) + " Quarter");
}
  else {
  (getQuarter (.38) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getQuarter(.38)*100/100) + " Quarters");
  };

   /* break  */ 

  if  (getDime(.38) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(.38)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if (getDime(.38) <= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(.38)*100/100) + " Dime");
}
  else {
  (getDime (.38) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getDime(.38)*100/100) + " Dimes");
  };
 
 /* break */

   if  (getNickel(.38) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(.38)*100/100) + " Dollar");
}
else if (getNickel(.38) <= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(.38)*100/100) + " Nickel");
}
  else {
  (getNickel (.38) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(getNickel(.38)*100/100) + " Nickels");
  };

/* break  */

  if (changeDue(.38) <= 0.0)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(.38)*100/100) + " Penny");
}
else if (changeDue(.38) >= 1)
{
println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(.38)*1000/100) + " Penny");
}
  else {
  (changeDue (.38) <= 2)
  println("You have "+ Math.round(changeDue(.38)*1000/100) + " Pennies");
  };
};
```

/* "End of Main() ") */

```
fun getDollar(a: Double): Double {return Math.floor(a) };

fun getQuarter(a: Double): Double {
return Math.floor(a/.25);
};

fun changeDue(a: Double): Double {
return (a%.25);
};

fun getDime(a: Double): Double {
return (a/.10);
};

fun getNickel(a: Double): Double {
return (a/.05);
};
```

Comment: What is the "1.22" that appears throughout the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting one function into multiple - Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235695/converting-one-function-into-multiple-kotlin)

Comment: the 1.22 is the test value to get it to run. (most times, it wasn't working, until I put that, vos the "var = 1.22". Idk why, but that's what was happening. lo)

Comment: Thanks for the post. It sorta does help, albeit I'm too tired now, to fully understand it. lol

(Though, I'm not sure it fully ans'd the problem of mine spitting out variations of the output, sometimes it matches the input, sometimes it either comes out as all "0s", or, is off by a digit or so.)

What I'm mostly trying to figure out, is why it's not splitting the code right.

Comment: Edit:

I looked again. It does give the needed code (albeit I'll need break it into 5 pcs), but I'll still need see 'why' mine fails. lol

Comment: Since this seems to be a school assignment, why not ask help there? I think you lack some basic understanding. It's the school's job to make you understand it. There's several mistakes in your code and I think it would be best if someone talks you through it and explain things, instead of someone writing up an answer for you.

Comment: Was the "Finals" assignment, already past since the 8th. ^_^

Was trying to rewrite it, so it worked properly. lol

However, the link above did give the ans I needed, albeit as a single block, & I had to rework it into separate blocks.

Managed to do it, but it doesn't work perfectly.

As far as help at the school > I will, when they're able. Was working w/ the teacher on it, but ran outta time (Finals being due & such)

Comment: @IvoBeckers Would you kindly explain the errors please? xD

(I can always wait til school starts again in Jan, to ask my instructors).

Answer (score 0):

Since I got the above to work, I wanted to aske why this top version (the "long, single-chain' Func) works "always", while the chopped version doesn't.

Also, any improvements on making the "chopped version" to be more consistent in it's answers, would be much appreciated.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var change = 3.27 ;
changeDue(change);
}

fun changeDue(change: Double){

var dollars = Math.floor(change/1.0);
var getDollar = change-(dollars*1.00);
print(Math.round(dollars*1)/1)
    if(dollars<2) println(" Dollar"); else if (dollars>=2) println(" 
Dollars")



var quarter = Math.floor(getDollar/0.25);
var change2 = getDollar-(quarter*0.25);
print(Math.round(quarter*4)/4)
    if(quarter<2) println(" Quarter"); else if (quarter>=2) println(" 
Quarters")


var dime = Math.floor(change2 / 0.10);
var change3 = change2 - (dime*0.10);
  print(Math.round(dime*10)/10)
    if(dime<2) println(" Dime") else if(dime>=2) println(" Dimes")


var nickel = Math.floor(change3 / 0.05);
var change4 = change3 - (nickel*0.05);
  print(Math.round(nickel*20)/20)
    if(nickel<2) println(" Nickel") else if (nickel>=2) println(" 
Nickels")


var penny = Math.floor(change4*100);
   print(Math.round(penny*100)/100)
    if(penny<2) println(" Penny") else if (penny>=2) println(" Pennies")

return Unit;
}
```

/* code as separate func blocks; Semi-broken  */

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

var change = 1.17

change -= getDollar(change)
change -= getQuarter(change)
change -= getDime(change)
change -= getNickel(change)
getPenny(change)

}


fun getDollar(myChange: Double): Double{
val dollar = myChange/(1.00).toDouble();
val change = myChange - (dollar * 1.00);
  print(Math.floor(dollar * 1)/1);
if(dollar<2) println(" Dollar"); else if (dollar>=2) println(" 
Dollars");
return change
}
fun getQuarter(myChange: Double): Double{
val quarter = myChange/(0.25).toDouble();
val change2 = myChange - (quarter * 0.25);
  print(Math.round(quarter*4)/25);
if(quarter<2) println(" Quarter"); else if (quarter>=2) println(" 
Quarters");
return change2
}
fun getDime(myChange: Double): Double{
val dime = myChange/(0.10).toDouble();
val change3 = myChange - (dime * 0.10);
  print(Math.round(dime * 10)/100);
if(dime<2) println(" Dime"); else if(dime>=2) println(" Dimes");
return change3
}
fun getNickel(myChange: Double): Double{
val nickel = myChange/(0.05).toDouble();
val change4 = myChange - (nickel * 0.05);
print(Math.round(nickel*20)/(20*20));
if(nickel<2) println(" Nickel"); else if (nickel>=2) println(" 
Nickels");
return change4
}
fun getPenny(myChange: Double){
val penny = (myChange/100);
  print(Math.round(penny * 10000)/ 100);
if(penny<2) println(" Penny"); else if (penny>=2) println(" Pennies");

return Unit
}
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear, can you please [edit] it and - 1, include details of how the problem was solved, 2, remove the question from answer, answers should not be used for asking.

Comment: How can the question be addressed, if the code isn't attached to it?

Also the "Answer" given, was cuz I didn't think it was appropriate to put the code + follow-up question, into the comments.

As far as how the above "fixes" the original answer - the code above, helps give the layout needed for the coding project I needed.

However, I still don't understand why the long version gives consistent answers whilst the broken one doesn't.

Comment: Also, the above doesn't fully answer the problem, as, it doesn't address the "many problems" someone noted I had, in my original coding.

OF which, if someone could clearly explain that, that would be helpful.

(I'm a greenhorn, as, I only started this Mid-Sept & "methods" was the last part we did.)

Comment: To better address this comment -

Actually, no. I can't explain much, other than I see the where the subtraction part goes, &, how to isolate the whole # from the decimal part.

However, I don't understand why that above, works any different than the 

    fun quarter (x: Double) Double { Return x/.25 }

    fun change (x: double) Double [ Return x%25 }

Much less why the inconsistency. (If I did understand these I wouldn't have been here..)